# use stream as source for wpf media element 

Tags: wpf, stream, video-streaming, media-player, xbap

Is there any way to set media element source as stream?
I know there is something in SL with:

```
SetSource()
```

is there anything like this in WPF? instead of Uri.

I have already array of bytes representing wave files and want to send the array to the wpf media element without having to create a file in the process.

Can you recommend on something??

Thanks!